# how can i change the value of variable just for a specific function?

Tags: python, function

```
x=2
def fun():
    y=x+2
    print(y)
def main_fun():
    x=10
    fun()

print(x)
fun()
main_fun()
fun()
print(x)
```

I want the that the value of x when i call main_fn be 10. But when i call fun() it will remain 2.
I have tried using global but it is not giving the required result.

I want this output:

```
2
4
12
4
2
```

Comment: Do you know what a *parameter* is, or an *argument*?

Comment: The `x` you are assigning in `main_fun()` is a *local variable*.  It has no existence outside of that function.

Comment: You can use the `global` keyword but this is usually bad practice... instead just pass values to other functions as parametes.

Comment: Python is *statically* scoped, not *dynamically* scope. If it were dynamically scoped, then setting `x` before you called `fun` work work as you expect. Most languages are statically scoped, because it's far easier to reason about how a function will work if you know what variables it is using without knowing where it is called.

Comment: At first i was not trying to to give parameters but after seeing your comment i just tried something and it worked perfectly. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Pass that value as an argument in that function
Suppose there is a variable `x`

```py
x=2
def fun(a=x)
   ...

def main_fun(a=y)
   ...

fun()
main_fun()
```

Instead you can also play with while calling

```py
x=2
def fun(a=x)
   ...

def main_fun(a=x)
   ...

fun()
main_fun(5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=2
def fun(x):
    y=x+2
    print(y)
def main_fun():
    y=10
    fun(y)

print(x)
fun(x)
main_fun()
fun(x)
print(x)
```

Comment: Please accompany your answer with an explanation